# Generic type with internal ID

Tags: scala, generics

I have a trait to represent a class with an ID.

I'm trying to achieve the following:

```scala
// Generic trait to represent a class with it's own type of ID
trait Entity[T <: Entity[T]] {
  self: T =>
  type ID

  final def withId(id: T#ID): IdAnd[T] = IdAnd(id, self)
}

// IdAnd can only have an idea matching the type T
case class IdAnd[T <: Entity[T]](id: T#ID, entity: T)

// Testing the usage

sealed trait Animal extends Entity[Animal] {
  override type ID = Long
}

case class Cat(name: String) extends Animal

object Animal {
  val test: IdAnd[Cat] = Cat("Garfield").withId(1L) // does not compile, returns an IdAnd[Animal]
}
```

In the example, how to get an `IdAnd[Cat]` and not an `IdAnd[Animal]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Cat` is inheriting `Entity[Animal]` from the `Animal` superclass, so the `self: T` from `Entity` is resolving as `Animal` instead of `Cat`.

If you change `Animal` to follow the same pattern that your `Entity` does, you can force the `case class` type to be used as the `T` instead of `Animal`:

```scala
sealed trait Animal[T <: Entity[T]] extends Entity[T] { self: T =>
  type ID = Long
}
case class Cat(name: String) extends Animal[Cat]
case class Dog(name: String) extends Animal[Dog]
```

That gets you

```
scala> Cat("Garfield").withId(1L)
val res0: IdAnd[Cat] = IdAnd(1,Cat(Garfield))

scala> Dog("Odie").withId(2L)
val res1: IdAnd[Dog] = IdAnd(2,Dog(Odie))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to make it work.

The first one is to NOT pin down `T` in `Animal` trait:

```
// Generic trait to represent a class with it's own type of ID
trait Entity[T <: Entity[T]] {
  self: T =>
  type ID

  final def withId(id: T#ID): IdAnd[T] = IdAnd(id, self)
}

// IdAnd can only have an idea matching the type T
case class IdAnd[T <: Entity[T]](id: T#ID, entity: T)

// Testing the usage

sealed trait Animal[T <: Animal[T]] extends Entity[T] { self: T =>
  override type ID = Long
}

case class Cat(name: String) extends Animal[Cat]

object Animal {
  val test: IdAnd[Cat] = Cat("Garfield").withId(1L) // does not compile, returns an IdAnd[Animal]
}
```

See [scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/MateuszKubuszok/pjkjaYIqRL62MTP6G99ijA/5).

The other are path dependent types:

```
trait Entity {
  type ID

  final def withId(id: this.ID): IdAnd[this.type] = IdAnd(this, id)
}

class IdAnd[+T <: Entity](val entity: T, val id: entity.ID)

sealed trait Animal extends Entity {
  override type ID = Long
}

case class Cat(name: String) extends Animal

val test: IdAnd[Cat] = Cat("Garfield").withId(1L)
```

See [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/MateuszKubuszok/lWwCRNEMRceAvz9lghvM0w/2).

Comment: I'm not able to compile your second solution, is here anything to do?

Comment: Depends what is the issue, I had to make IdAnd's T covariant, so that it could be upcasted from `IdAnd[something <: Cat]` to `IdAnd[Cat]`

Comment: `IdAnd` is not compiling: not found: value entity
illegal dependent method type: parameter may only be referenced in a subsequent parameter section

Comment: It's Scala 2's limitation, you can split contructor to `(val entity: T)(val id: entity.ID)`

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still not able to make it work, do you have a working example for the solution 2 using scala 2? Thanks